# Java: How to listen on a socket while doing other things

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I'm starting to get deeper into Java and wanted to clear up a few ideas/questions I had regarding the subject.

In java what options are available to listen on a port while doing other activities in your code.  Then be able to execute code when traffic is detected.

Is implementing a Server instance with threading the only option?
Or can event handlers provide similar functionality?

Even though this seems possible to me, I'm sure it is not:
Is a `java.net.ServerSocket` instance even necessary since `java.net.Socket` can receive messages as well?  Or can `java.net.Socket` only receive responses from the messages it sends out.

Thank you for any help in advanced.

Comment: [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: `ServerSocket` is required to initiate the initial in coming request for communication.  A `Socket` can only establish the out going connection (broadly speaking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 'side-question', yes, you will want to use a ServerSocket.

For doing other work while also listening to the socket, however, this is an issue of concurrency. You must dispatch a thread in the background that will listen on that servlet. On a basic level, this could be accomplished by creating a 'Worker' class which implements the `Runnable` interface. The `public void run()` method will have code that listens on the socket as one would normally do.

Once you have defined a worker class, you can create a thread which will execute your socket-listening logic in the background. `new Thread(anInstanceOfYourWorkerClass).start();` will create your thread and run your worker logic. This is of course a basic example.

Answer (score 1):

ServerSocket is the class to use if you want to listen on a port. But to do other things while listening requires that you use multiple threads. This is because the accept() call blocks until a connection is made.